# Should movement be predicted to avoid GPS battery kill?

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation, gps, location

I have been working on a navigation application where I update my location as I pull GPS location changes. The problem I am encountering is that, in order to keep battery life up, I have implemented a fused location provider that attempts to set my request intervals:

```
locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
locationRequest.setInterval(ARBITRARY_INTERVAL_TIME);
locationRequest.setFastestInterval(ARBITRARY_MIN_TIME);
locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(ARBITRARY_MIN_DIST);

// locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
locationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, this);
```

Where my values are:

`ARBITRARY_INTERVAL_TIME = 30000
 ARBITRARY_MIN_TIME = 15000
 ARBITRARY_MIN_DIST = 25`

And drawing my navigation icon like so:

```
// Draw navigation icon
if(navigationMarkerHolder != null){
    navigationMarkerHolder.remove();
}
LatLng coords = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
BitmapDescriptor navigationIcon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.navigation);
    navigationMarker.title("Current position");
    navigationMarker.icon(navigationIcon);
    navigationMarker.position(coords);
    navigationMarker.anchor(.5f,.5f);
    navigationMarker.rotation(loc.getBearing());
navigationMarkerHolder = map.addMarker(navigationMarker);
```

The issue I have with this is that, in only pulling updates every ~20 seconds, I only update my navigation icon every ~20 seconds which makes my navigation icon look choppy. Native Android navigation seems to constantly update your position and bearing, but to pull constant updates seems like it would drain the battery pretty quickly. Is Google really predicting movement or is it actually pulling updates? If it is getting updates, how is it doing it without risking battery drain. When I tried to get GPS updates every 5-10 seconds my battery life suffered pretty severely.

Comment: Have you tried to measure how much battery will `LocationClient` drain compared to having device display turned on and redrawing map 60fps? Sounds like a premature optimization question.

Comment: I'm asking how Google manages to make their navigation "appear" to update every few seconds. Do they actually get location updates that often or are they predicting movement? I'm honestly a little confused by your comment, I'm sorry. Could you possibly elaborate. I don't care to alter my location client, and I don't want to draw at 60fps. I just want to know how Google manages to update without killing the battery.

Comment: They are claiming `LocationClient` takes 1% of battery per hour, so I would not worry about this too much and use default frequent updates.

Comment: Default is 45 seconds with simple GPS, and can be more. Hence the fused location provider and it's set intervals. But ~10 second intervals would eat ~6% just on GPS meaning ~10-15% from just my app and STILL 10 second updates where native looks around 5. So, how?

Comment: @MaciejGórski sorry forgot to tag you

Comment: You would probably have to ask Google engineers or look into their code. ;)

Comment: @MaciejGórski blasted Google gurus